# How to select specific records from a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to perform the below logic. I have a table with several fields and from that table I have to select prod that has group as c but not d. Some prods will have group as c as well as d. And from the selected prods, I have to select other fields such as latitude, longitude etc.

From the below table, using SQL, how do I retrieve the highlighted rows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding that by "c" you meant "i" and by "d" you meant "f"
Below does this.
It identifies those Prod's that are in "i" group but not in "f" group

```
SELECT Prod
FROM (
  SELECT Prod, 
    CONCAT('|', GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(group, '|'), '|') AS list 
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY Prod
)
WHERE list CONTAINS '|i|' 
AND NOT list CONTAINS '|f|'
```

You can test this with below

```
SELECT Prod
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Prod, 
    CONCAT('|', GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(group, '|'), '|') AS list 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'prod1' AS Prod, 'i' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod1' AS Prod, 'f' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod1' AS Prod, 'f' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod2' AS Prod, 'i' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod3' AS Prod, 'i' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod4' AS Prod, 'i' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod4' AS Prod, 'f' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod4' AS Prod, 'f' AS group),
    (SELECT 'prod4' AS Prod, 'f' AS group),
  GROUP BY Prod
)
WHERE list CONTAINS '|i|' 
AND NOT list CONTAINS '|f|'
```

so you final query can look something like

```
SELECT <list of needed fields>
FROM YourTable
WHERE Prod IN (
  SELECT Prod
  FROM (
    SELECT Prod, 
      CONCAT('|', GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(group, '|'), '|') AS list 
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Prod
  )
  WHERE list CONTAINS '|i|' 
  AND NOT list CONTAINS '|f|'
)
```

Comment: abouve query was very useful in constructing what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using the most basic of SQL i.e. use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT <the_cols_you_want> FROM [<Dataset.Table>] WHERE Prod in ('prod2','prod3') and Group = 'i'
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/